# NoClassDefFoundError in Azure Function App for Digital Twin

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-digital-twins

I am developing an azure function app. function in azure function app is responsible to receive messages from azure event hub. this method should should update azure digital twin. I am creating `Azure DigitalTwin` instance like below

```
@FunctionName("eventGridMonitorString")
    public void eventHubProcessor(
            @EventHubTrigger(name = "msg", eventHubName = "", connection = "EventHubConnectionString") String message,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
//      context.getLogger().info(message);
        String adtUrl = System.getenv("ADT_SERVICE_URL");
        context.getLogger().info("ADTURl : " + adtUrl);

        DigitalTwinsClient client = new DigitalTwinsClientBuilder().credential(new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .tenantId("my_tenant_id").clientId("my_client_id")
                .clientSecret("my_client_secret").build()).endpoint(adtUrl).buildClient();

        Iterable<DigitalTwinsModelData> modelList = client.listModels();
        Iterator<DigitalTwinsModelData> it = modelList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            DigitalTwinsModelData model = it.next();
            context.getLogger().info("" + model.getDtdlModel());
        }
        for (DigitalTwinsModelData model : modelList) {
            context.getLogger().info("Created model: " + model.getModelId());
        }

    }
```

This code works fine in my local java application but when I deploy this code to azure function app, it gives me below error

```
2021-05-27T07:42:35.173 [Error] Executed 'Functions.eventGridMonitorString' (Failed, Id=12a87102-78a3-4e2e-8715-b4401091d753, Duration=116ms)Result: FailureException: NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfigStack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(JavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:54)at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:57)at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfigat reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect.<init>(HttpClientConnect.java:84)at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.create(HttpClient.java:393)at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.build(NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.java:91)at com.azure.core.http.netty.implementation.ReactorNettyClientProvider.createInstance(ReactorNettyClientProvider.java:14)at com.azure.core.implementation.http.HttpClientProviders.createInstance(HttpClientProviders.java:58)at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:50)at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:40)at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineBuilder.build(HttpPipelineBuilder.java:62)at com.azure.digitaltwins.core.DigitalTwinsClientBuilder.buildPipeline(DigitalTwinsClientBuilder.java:151)at com.azure.digitaltwins.core.DigitalTwinsClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(DigitalTwinsClientBuilder.java:193)at com.azure.digitaltwins.core.DigitalTwinsClientBuilder.buildClient(DigitalTwinsClientBuilder.java:160)at com.ey.azurefunctions.PolarDelightFunctionApp.Function.eventHubProcessor(Function.java:32)... 16 more
```

am I missing something or is there any issue with above code?

**Edit 1** I have below maven dependencies added to my project

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-digitaltwins-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core-http-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version> <!-- {x-version-update;com.azure:azure-core-http-netty;dependency} -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.49.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-bom</artifactId>
            <version>Dysprosium-SR20</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I think it is related to this issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/19041 did you manage to solve the dependencies?